# error when import vtk in python on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-import, vtk, importerror

When I try to import vtk, it doesn't work.
I tried [this method](https://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/vetvis/ht10/vtk/instructions_vtk_OSX.pdf) (build the vtk with cmake and update environment variables - except the "Post installation tasks"), but I still have :

```
$python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named vtk
```

I tried before that

```
sudo brew install python-vtk
```

but it returns :

```
Error: No available formula with the name "python-vtk" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

How can I import vtk in my Python code on my Mac computer without problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the darwin dmg file here;

http://www.vtk.org/download/#latestcand

Comment: I have a problem : when I'm in the vtkpython directory and I run ./vtkpython my importation of vtk works. But when I'm in a normal python console, it returns : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "vtk/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .vtkCommonCore import *
  File "vtk/vtkCommonCore.py", line 9, in <module>
    from vtkCommonCorePython import *
ImportError: No module named vtkCommonCorePython`
What can I do to import vtk anywhere I want ?

Comment: Confirm that the vtk binary folder is in your system path. Type;  echo $PATH in a console and see if the vtk folder is in the output. If not add it.

Comment: I did it : when I `echo $PATH` I didn't have the path. I added it with `PATH=$PATH:/Users/Hello/Applications/vtkpython/bin` but when I run `python` and I want to `import vtk` or `import vtkpython` or `import python-vtk` it returns `Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: No module named vtk`. I already tried `pip2 install vtkpython` which returns `Collecting vtkpython
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtkpython (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for vtkpython`. What can I do ?

Comment: Can you confirm the other exports? What does echo  $LD_LIBRARY_PATH return?

Comment: I do what [they](https://macosx.com/threads/problems-with-dyld-ld_library_path.240354/) say and see the variables DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH and DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH (the mac version of LD_LIBRARY_PATH) and they seem to be empty... Why did you want that ?

Comment: Doesn't the export commands work? LIke this; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Hello/Applications/vtkpython/bin/  Also, fwiw, I would move it out of applications. Maybe Applications permissions is screwing you.

Comment: When I did `export $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Hello/mynewlocation/vtkpython/bin/` and I run `import vtk` or `import vtkpython` in python console => `ImportError: No module named vtkpython`. And when I close and reopen a terminal and try `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, it's empty !

Comment: leave the $ sign off in the export.